# Resolving mercurial conflicts in beyond compare pro

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, beyondcompare, beyondcompare4

I am using tortoiseHg and beyond compare 4 pro for a java project.
When I encounter a conflict beyond compare opens a 2-diff view but it doesn't let me edit anything!!!!

Please Help!!

Thanks

Comment: Have followed the steps on [their site](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?c=kb_vcs.php)?

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the [TortoiseHG configuration instructions](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs#mercurial) from Beyond Compare's website?

If you've followed the above instructions and it didn't resolve the problem, what version of TortoiseHG are you using?

Comment: I'm having the same problem and the instructions on the site to only set the "visual diff tool" setting to beyondcompare4 did not work for me.  I'm using the standard version of Beyond Compare 4.1 (Build 20575) and version 3.5.1 of TortoiseHG.  When I was using a "trial" version of Beyond Compare it showed the 3 way merge screen and everything worked as expected.  Since putting in my license key for Beyond Compare I now see the standard compare screen and nothing is editable.

Comment: The trial version of Beyond Compare defaults to running in Pro mode, which supports 3-way merge. Beyond Compare Standard doesn't support 3-way merge. It is limited to 2-way comparison. If you want to use 3-way merge, you'll need to upgrade your license to Pro by paying the difference in license price. To put Beyond Compare back into trial mode to evaluate pro features, follow the instructions here: http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_evalpro

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Beyond Compare Standard with TortoiseHg you will need to modify the MergeTools.rc file located at `C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\hgrc.d\MergeTools.rc`.

I needed to modify this line:

```
beyondcompare4.args=$local $other $base /mergeoutput=$output /ro /lefttitle=parent1 /centertitle=base /righttitle=parent2 /outputtitle=merged /automerge /reviewconflicts /solo
```

To be this:

```
beyondcompare4.args=$other $local /savetarget=$output /lro /title1=parent1 /title2=parent2 /automerge /reviewconflicts /solo
```